# for cycle not works allright

Tags: java, for-loop

I call addNotify() method in class that I posted here. The problem is, that when I call addNotify() as it is in the code, setKeys(objs) do nothing. Nothing appears in my explorer of running app.

But when I call addNotify()without loop(for int....), and add only one item to ArrayList, it shows that one item correctly.

Does anybody know where can be problem? See the cede

```
class ProjectsNode extends Children.Keys{
private ArrayList objs = new ArrayList();

public ProjectsNode() {


}

    @Override
protected Node[] createNodes(Object o) {
    MainProject obj = (MainProject) o;
    AbstractNode result = new AbstractNode (new DiagramsNode(), Lookups.singleton(obj));
    result.setDisplayName (obj.getName());
    return new Node[] { result };
}

@Override
protected void addNotify() {
    //this loop causes nothing appears in my explorer.
    //but when I replace this loop by single line "objs.add(new MainProject("project1000"));", it shows that one item in explorer
    for (int i=0;i==10;i++){
        objs.add(new MainProject("project1000"));
    }
    setKeys (objs);
}
```

}

Comment: retag: this q really did not have any 'netbeans-ness' to it.

Comment: originally it was question why addNotify does not work. I edited title after revealing the essence of problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at this loop:

```
for (int i=0;i==10;i++)
```

That's going to start with i = 0, and keep going *while i == 10*. I think you meant:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

(Extra whitespace added just for clarity.)

Answer (score 1):

Jon is right... your loop is very likely to be incorrect.

Here is a translation of your for-loop into a while loop, just to clarify his observation even more...

Your loop currently means this... (in while-loop-ness)

```
int i = 0;

while (i==10) {
    objs.add(new MainProject("project1000"));
    i++;
}
setKeys (objs);
```

The addNotify is never called because add is never called...

Comment: this is surprise for me. Alhough I have not so much experience in programming, I used for cycle a lot of times. And this never happend to me till now.

Comment: No, you haven’t used the `for` loop like this and have had it working because *it does not work*.

Comment: @Bombe - I do not write "like this". So, yes, I used for cycle for a couple of years and I've never had this problem.

Comment: Of course, when using the `for` loop correctly it does indeed work. Unfortunately “using the `for` loop correctly” has nothing to do with what you have done. :)